# Undefined limit 1 to the power infinity

Tags: limits

Take $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=1$. Then  $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)^x$ is undefined because the limit can take various values. My question is the following: For any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, can I find $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)^x=a$? For example this is clearly true for 1 or $e$, but can I construct such a function for every real number?

Comment: Well, how about $f(x) = a^{1/x}$?

Comment: If $a$ is positive take $f(x)=a^{\frac{1}{x}}$.

Comment: "*...then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)^x$ is undefined*"  No, it can be defined.  It depends on what $f$ is specifically.  Without more specific knowledge of $f$ we can not say whether the limit will be undefined or defined and what the limit will be, but that is not the same thing as saying it is always undefined for all $f$ which is how your phrasing sounds like you are saying.  It is merely unknown until further scrutinized with more detail.  You probably mean to say "[indeterminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form)".

Answer (score 1):

As you have been told in the comments, if $a>0$,then you can just take $f(x)=a^{1/x}$.

If $a=0$, you can take $f(x)=e^{-1/\sqrt x}$.

And if $a<0$, then the problem has no solution, since $f(x)^x\geqslant0$ if $f(x)\geqslant0$.